# Список сетевых подключений delphi 7

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Как получить список сетевых подключений средствами Delphi 7?

Если искать через реестр, то там ВСЕ подключения (в т.ч. и удаленные или только удаленные, хз, толком не смотрел).

Мне необходимо получить список активных подключений, типа, "Подключение по локальной сети* 2", "Ethernet" и т.п.

Comment: через WMI получаются все подключения, из delphi можно орудовать с WMI

Comment: http://rouse.drkb.ru/files/netifenum.zip

Comment: @user212880 не могли бы вы пояснить, что там за архив по ссылке?

Answer (score 1):

Наиболее рабочий и адекватный вариант дал @user212880 (жалко, что вы не оформили ваш вариант как ответ, так бы получили плюс =) )

В ссылке этот пользователь скинул пример рабочей программы, которая (каким-то магическим для меня методом) обходит весь список сетевых подключений и даже выдает подробную информацию о каждом из них

Answer (score 0):

Есть два основных варианта:

1. [WMI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384642(v=vs.85).aspx)
2. [IP Helper API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366073(v=vs.85).aspx)

В частности, для WMI нужно сделать выборку из [Win32_NetworkAdapter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394216(v=vs.85).aspx), а для IP Helper - воспользоваться [GetAdaptersInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365917(v=vs.85).aspx).

Пример от Rouse_ использует как раз IP Helper.